# Create ZipArchive in memory then download to client

Tags: c#, http, zip

I have read several blog posts and questions about this, but I can't get this working.  It just downloads a corrupt ZIP archive that is <2KB.  I feel like I'm missing something simple with streaming the PDF file to the Zip Archive?

```
       using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (string Item in Items)
            {
                ReportParameter[] prms = new ReportParameter[1];
                prms[0] = new ReportParameter("Item", Item, false);

                rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(prms);

                rv.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
                rv.ServerReport.Refresh();

                byte[] bytes = rv.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

                string fileName = Item + ".pdf";
                var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);
                using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }
        outStream.Position = 0;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=PDFReports_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip");
        Response.Write(outStream);
    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in, what's the length of `bytes`? It also might help to append a `Content-Length` header

Comment: Also, what happens if you simply return the PDF file (ignoring the zipping for now)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working on this remotely without dev tools so debugging is a huge pain :p  I believe I tested the PDF portion successfully at the beginning of this project but I will try that again.